# What is the distribution of items received from a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

Like for example, what's the chance of getting a Great Ball? What are the probabilities if you've unlocked all the items, versus if a Great Ball was the last thing unlocked?

Comment: Are you asking for a list showing the chances of each drop from a Pokestop? This question is currently unclear :/

Comment: Helpful, but incomplete, studies: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w3jkd/study_on_pokestops_drop_rate_of_specific_items_in/ and also https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4uy51o/does_anyone_know_the_drop_rate_for_specific_items/

Comment: As of now, there is no information as to what kind of drop rates Pokestops have. This is unlikely to be discovered in the future, as this information is server-side, and will never be released unless Niantic decides to do so. In its current state, this question is *unanswerable*.

Comment: @KazWolfe I don't agree. This is a directly measurable result, so it is *very* answerable.

Comment: @Schism true. It could be answered through observation, but not exactly. There is always going to be some randomness / bias.

Comment: @KazWolfe Of course there'll be some bias, but with enough data you should be able to get a fairly good estimate. Of course, there's the matter of actually doing the experiment :-)

Comment: @Schism Yeah well, laziness and all. ^-^

Comment: I believe the drop rates do vary from level-to-level (ie some items are easier to obtain), especially for levels where you unlock new items. Would need **a lot** of data to sufficiently cover all of them, but certainly doable.

Comment: Since pokestop items are restricted by trainer level, item drop rates will vary up to level 30.  Even for statistical counts, Niantic can (and has) easily adjust the drop rates at any time.  If you wanted to calculate expected numbers, you also need to know the distribution of items received.  At best, this question is hard to answer and would require a lengthy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a user's logs [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4whv63/3207_pokestops_data/) for 3207 Pokestops (with all items unlocked), a rough estimate of the drop rates for items for Pokestops is as follows:

[image]

Since then, the drop rates have changed, as you can see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/58h2jr/item_drop_rate_checkin/?), however, the rates are pretty much the same, but with lower rates for Pokeballs and Revives and higher rates for Potions and Super Potions.

> **The results:**
>
> - Pokeballs: 599 (52.00 %)
> - Great balls: 132 (11.46 %)
> - Ultra balls: 37 (3.21 %)
> - Razzberries: 82 (7.12 %)
> - **Total balls/berries: 850 (73.78%)**
> - Potions: 134 (11.63 %)
> - Super Potions: 67 (5.82 %)
> - Hyper Potions: 25 (2.17 %)
> - Max Potions: 8 (0.69%)
> - **Total potions: 234 (20.31%)**
> - Revives: 62 (5.38 %)
> - Max Revives: 6 (0.52%)
> - **Total revives: 68 (5.90%)**

Comment: Careful. They swapped around the drop rates a few patches ago, the information you linked is from 3 months ago and might be out of date.

Comment: @Karlyr, found more recent data. It looks like they're pretty much the same, but slightly diff rates for pokeballs, revives, and regular/super potions.

Comment: Just good to notice that Niantic could easily swap around drop rates at a moment notice juste to change a bit the balance of the game. Still pretty useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this information has not been officially released by Niantic, nor has it been thoroughly tested enough by current users to provide a concrete conclusion.

However, some preliminary tests have been conducted by interested users. Here are two examples of the most comprehensive unofficial tests I could find, which can be found [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w3jkd/study_on_pokestops_drop_rate_of_specific_items_in/?utm_source=mweb_redirect&compact=true) and [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4uy51o/does_anyone_know_the_drop_rate_for_specific_items/?utm_source=mweb_redirect&compact=true).